# Hide woocmmerce payment gateways if user comes from given page on wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

Am trying to hide paypal payment gateway for a digital product. For some complex reason I have to hide the payment gateway not entirely for the product, but if the user proceeds to checkout from another page (referrer page). Here is the code I tried to put together, but it doesnot hide the gateway. Any assistance will be appretiated.

```
//hide paypal if user access checkout from "send money" page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'dealion_payment_gateway_disable_onpage' );
function dealion_payment_gateway_disable_onpage( $available_gateways ) {
$referer=wp_get_referer();
var_dump($referer);

if ( isset( $available_gateways['paypal'] ) && $referer== "https://www.myshop.store/send-money/") {
  unset( $available_gateways['paypal'] );

}
return $available_gateways;
}
```

Comment: How is `redirect_url()` called? Also, I think trying to work with the PHP Session isn't a great idea, it will cause problems on your site, since the session is started at init, but left open. It will cause errors with "loopback request" and break a lot of stuff. Use either a cookie, or why can't you just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in your if statement?

Comment: @HowardE, thanks for pointing out a few things that were not right in the code. I removed the unnecessary redirect_url() and tried to rewrite the code a little bit. It's not working yet but I believe am close. You could pick it from here. Thanks

Comment: If you `var_dump($referer)` what do you get on the checkout page?

Comment: @HowardE, actually I don't know how i can plug that in the code....would you please show me how i should plug it, and in what line....My php skills are just intermediate

Comment: immediately after `$referer = wp_get_referer();` - make sure the referring URL is what you expect.  That's all this will do.

Comment: @HowardE, thank you....When I get to the checkout page from the referring page (send-money), the paypal gateway is hidden, but when woocommerce completes loading payment options, paypal appears again.Some text also shows up on the checkout page: [string(38) "https://www.myshop.store/send-money/"] - that appears at the top of the checkout page. And this: [string(38) "https://www.myshop.store/send-money/" string(36) "https://www.myshop.store/checkout/"] - that appears just before the woocommerce available payment options. I disabled caching for the two pages

Comment: You can upvote the answer as well if you find it to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `WC()->session` and store a custom variable so that it doesn't clear your referrer.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'dealion_payment_gateway_disable_onpage' );
function dealion_payment_gateway_disable_onpage( $available_gateways ) {
    // Don't check gateways on Admin.
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $available_gateways;
    }
    if ( null === WC()->session->get( 'dealion_referer' ) ) {
        // Get the Referer and Store in a WC Session Var.
        $referer = wp_get_referer();
        WC()->session->set( 'dealion_referer', $referer );
    } else {
        $referer = WC()->session->get( 'dealion_referer' );
    }
    if ( isset( $available_gateways['paypal'] ) && 'https://www.myshop.store/send-money/' === $referer ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['paypal'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```